# How to flatten out database structure?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've seen a lot of posts that suggest having a flatter structure instead of nesting  items. My question is how would I possibly flatten this out?

```
    {
  "GroceryItems" : {
    "Meat&Seafood" : {
      "1234" : {
        "category" : "C",
        "grams" : false,
        "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lesn-1dcc8.appspot.com/o/pork-loin-steaks-23_3.jpg?alt=media&token=06e4fc13-b997-498b-8649-e2d6ee3967f0",
        "inStock" : false,
        "itemID" : 1234,
        "name" : "Pork Loin",
        "price" : "$4/piece",
        "productDesc" : "Freshly cut Pork Loin, thin and juicy, taste great when fire grilled."
      },
      "fdsasda" : {
        //same stuff
      },
      "kfdsopwj1" : {
        //same stuff
      },
      "ofejsadi01" : {
       //same stuff

  },
```

I've looked at other examples and don't understand it, and when I try to change it, it fails.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by changing your database structure?

Comment: This structure should be good enough, but it mostly depends on what operation are you trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but what if I want to search through the database for a specific string. Is this structure still good?

Comment: Im not really trying to solve any problems, the firebase docs just said to flatten it out. I just wasnt sure if I was doing it right.